# How to switch between clusters on live with spring data couchbase

Tags: spring-data-couchbase

We have two clusters, one is active, the other is passive, in case they are switched from one to another, our application will be notified in this case to change the cluster and the hosts accordingly. So is it possible to do the switch on live and how please?

Comment: There is no current support for multi-cluster awareness in Spring data couchbase, but it is on the roadmap (no specific timeline). However, there is a standalone client support for enterprise customers.